# Virtual terminal with at least 16bit color?

Tags: command-line, terminal, color-depth, virtual-terminal

It's 2013 and there should be terminals with more than 256 colors by now (you'd think).

Are there any terminals with more than 8bit colors (usually from 8 bit we jump to 16bit) to use with linux?

Ideally, I'd like to have a linux terminal with 32bit colors for the foreground and background of each character. So, the functionality would be the same, with escape sequences, but just more of them (or something like that?).

Comment: Why do you need more than 256? That's actually quite a lot of them.

Comment: @normalocity Why not? Why do you need more than 256 in any modern environment like HTML/CSS, or Photoshop, or Gimp? Because it's nice. :) Sure, we can *live* with 256 colors, but I want more. Just like how everyone wants a better smart phone, but they don't *need* to get the latest phone every time a new one is out, but it's nice to have the option. For one, I'd be able to write a scripted colorscheme for vim who's colors change along a gradient (instead of noticeable color steps).

Comment: Except you can argue that different or new functionality (such as viewing photos in near-original color) is a feature of newer, better phones - I don't know that you can say the same thing for more colors in a terminal. It's perfectly fine to say, "Why not?" but the question itself isn't an answer.

Comment: @normalocity That's true. I can live with 256 color, but I'd simply like it for aesthetics and enjoyment. I simply feel I'd enjoy having more color to play with. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the new [kmscon](https://github.com/dvdhrm/kmscon) userspace console. It runs in KMS/DRM mode (like the Linux console) and support 256 colors, and vector fonts.